# Using \restoregeometry in environment, next page runs off the page bottom

Tags: margins, geometry

The problem is as follows.

In a `memoir` document, I defined the page geometry:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=5.25in,
paperheight=8in,
textwidth=95mm,
textheight=150mm,
outer=17mm
}
\setlength{\stockwidth}{5.25in}
\setlength{\stockheight}{8in}
\addtolength{\headheight}{5pt}
```

Then I defined an environment to put a piece of text dead centre on a page:

```
\newenvironment{quotepage}[1]%
{\newpage\newgeometry{margin=0pt}%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\bgroup\centering%
\noindent\par\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vfill%
\begin{minipage}{#1}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
}{\end{minipage}%
\vfill\egroup%
\restoregeometry}
```

When using this environment,

```
\begin{quotepage}{0.7\linewidth}
\itshape
What is the Noble Truth of Suffering? ...

Saṃyutta Nikāya 56.11, Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta
\end{quotepage}
```

The next page (the one after `\restoregeometry` was called) will begin with good header and textwidth, but the page content runs way off the page at the bottom. The page after that has good header, footer, text width, height and all.

[image: text runs off the page]

However, this doesn't happen if I don't use an environment. If I just copy-paste the code which the environment should insert, the page after `\restoregeometry` is good, and so are the rest.

Very puzzling. Something is going wrong with how I defined the environment, but I can't figure it out. Can someone see the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using a group too many and don't restore properly the geometry, as the `\restoregeometry` command is issued when LaTeX is still processing the environment, which forms a group:

```
\newenvironment{quotepage}[1]
  {\newpage
   \newgeometry{margin=0pt}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \centering
   \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
   \begin{minipage}{#1}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0.6\baselineskip}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  }
  {\end{minipage}
   \vfill
   \clearpage
   \aftergroup\restoregeometry
  }
```

You may want to look at other solutions, for example TikZ provides the ability to put nodes at the physical page center.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox{\quotepagebox}
\newenvironment{quotepage}[1]
  {\begin{lrbox}{\quotepagebox}\begin{minipage}{#1}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0.6\baselineskip}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
   \node at (current page.center) {\usebox{\quotepagebox}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \clearpage}
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat codeblock! I'll look into the tikz node business too, sounds much simpler.

Comment: @Nyiti You may want to look at the code provided in my last edit.

Comment: @egreg that works, but it removes `\doublespacing` in my case. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ghx That might depend on many factors; please, ask a new question with all the needed details.

Comment: @egreg ok please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552734/afterpage-and-newgeometry-spacing-issue

Answer (score 2):

As `egreg` said, `\restoregeometry` must be executed outside the environment.

You can use the `\AfterEndEnvironment`-hook from the `etoolbox` package for that.

From the `etoolbox` documentation:

> `\AfterEndEnvironment{environment}{code}`
>
> Appends arbitrary `code` to a hook executed at a very late point by the `\end`
>   command, after the group holding the environment has been closed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{Hello!}{Bye!}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{myenv}{\newgeometry{left=5mm,right=5mm,top=5mm,bottom=5mm}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{myenv}{\restoregeometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myenv}
Test
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the MWE in dual view. Despite page 2 having newgeometry, text on page 3 does not run off the page bottom.]