# scrlayer-scrpage: Footer only on first page, adjust geometry

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage

I have a problem during the re-creation of a Word template concerning [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage?lang=de) and possibly the [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=de) package inside a KOMA-script document class.

My template has a constant header in the whole document and a footer, but only on the first page. Usually, this is no problem. However, in the original template, the space occupied by the footer on the first page is added to the text area on the following pages. So I need something like `includefoot=true` inside the `geometry` definition of the first page and `includefoot=false` on all following pages.

I hope the following pictures explain what I want to achieve. The current state: on the left, the first page has the footer. On the right, the second page has all the white space where the empty footer is.

[image]
[image]

I want to add the footer space for every page from page 2 to the end as shown on the right:

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, I only achieve the desired result for page 2 and forward for `includefoot=false` which messes up the footer on the first page. I tried to use `newgeometry` after my title section, but as explained in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53499/newgeometry-makes-content-run-to-next-page) this works on full pages and my first section is moved to the second page. I do not want that.

Is there a possibility to switch geometry definitions without jumping to a new page or anything else that solves my problem?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,parskip=half-,11pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ---------------------------
% Packages
% ---------------------------

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{coffee4}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=true,
  headsep = \dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

% ---------------------------
% Template adjustments
% ---------------------------

% Title
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  % Zweck
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    Test
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  % Authors
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X}%
      \@author
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Title
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    \@title%
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  %\vskip 1.5em%
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Beschreibung des Vorhabens
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    Schalala
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
}
\makeatother

% Font sizes
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% ---------------------------
% Header/Footer commands
% ---------------------------

% Clear old  headers/footers
\clearpairofpagestyles

% Fonts for headers/footers
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

% Trennlinien fuer Kopf und Fuss
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline = false,
  footsepline = false,
  plainfootsepline = false,
}

% Create new header for title page
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    \textbf{An organization}\\
    With an address\\
    and communication channels
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \cfoot{Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only}
  \ofoot{\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}
}
% Page Layout for normal pages
\newpairofpagestyles{normalpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{}
  \ofoot{}
}

% Abstaende
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subparagraph}

% 
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{normalpage}

\section{First section}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Blindtext[2]

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\Blindtext[6]

\section{Second section}

\cofeAm{1}{0.85}{0}{0.25\textwidth}{-0.25\textheight} % needs \usepackage{coffee4}
\Blindtext[9]
\cofeDm{0.5}{0.2}{0}{-0.35\textwidth}{-0.4\textheight} % needs \usepackage{coffee4}

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

using the approach proposed by @UlrikeFischer:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,parskip=half-,11pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ---------------------------
% Packages
% ---------------------------

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{coffee4}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  %bottom=20mm,
  %includefoot=true,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = \dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

% ---------------------------
% Template adjustments
% ---------------------------

% Title
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  % Zweck
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    Test
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  % Authors
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X}%
      \@author
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Title
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    \@title%
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  %\vskip 1.5em%
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Beschreibung des Vorhabens
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    Schalala
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
}
\makeatother

% Font sizes
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% ---------------------------
% Header/Footer commands
% ---------------------------

% Clear old  headers/footers
\clearpairofpagestyles

% Fonts for headers/footers
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

% Trennlinien fuer Kopf und Fuss
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline = false,
  footsepline = false,
  plainfootsepline = false,
}

% Create new header for title page
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \textbf{An organization}\\
      With an address\\
      and communication channels
      \end{tabular}
    }
  }
  \cfoot{
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only
    }
  }
  \ofoot{
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}
      %\normalsize
    }
  }
}
% Page Layout for normal pages
\newpairofpagestyles{normalpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{}
  \ofoot{}
}

% Abstaende
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subparagraph}

% 
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\enlargethispage{-1cm}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{normalpage}

\section{First section}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Blindtext[2]

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\Blindtext[6]

\section{Second section}

\Blindtext[9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

What happens with the `\ofoot`?

Comment: Use \enlargethispage{-1cm} (or whatever) on the first page and let the footer stick into the textbody.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. But if I use `\enlargethispage{-1cm} ` and `includefoot=false` my footer on the first page is still stuck at the very bottom of the page which does not look nice. Additionally, I would later like to use this as a template without much user influence.

Comment: It is easy to move content around, e.g. with \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{TEXT OF THE FOOTER}.  I don't understand your remark about the user. Why should he/she care if you use \enlargethispage or \newgeometry or something else to change the layout of the first page?

Comment: I already tried using a `raisebox` but the behaviour is kind of weird for the `ofoot`. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Spaces matters in tex. So add % after opening braces. Beside this you are getting exactly what you are asking for. Every three part have their baseline aligned. If you don't want the XXX to move up, well then don't move it up ...

Comment: Thanks, I already added the `%`.  The thing about XYZ on the right is that I do not raise it at all it is too low. However, if I raise it the same amount as the `lfoot` it is higher. Is that due to the higher font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update you simple need to change your command `\raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]` in command `\ofoot` to for example `\raisebox{0cm}[0pt][0pt]`.  Please see that I changed the first parameter `1cm` to `0cm`.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  parskip=half-,
  11pt
]{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ---------------------------
% Packages
% ---------------------------

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{coffee4}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = \dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

% ---------------------------
% Template adjustments
% ---------------------------

% Title
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  % Zweck
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    Test
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  % Authors
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X}%
      \@author
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Title
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    \@title%
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  %\vskip 1.5em%
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Beschreibung des Vorhabens
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    Schalala
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
}
\makeatother

% Font sizes
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% ---------------------------
% Header/Footer commands
% ---------------------------

% Clear old  headers/footers
\clearpairofpagestyles

% Fonts for headers/footers
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

% Trennlinien fuer Kopf und Fuss
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline = false,
  footsepline = false,
  plainfootsepline = false,
}

% Create new header for title page
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \textbf{An organization}\\
      With an address\\
      and communication channels
      \end{tabular}
    }
  }
  \cfoot{
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only
    }
  }
  \ofoot{
    \raisebox{0cm}[0pt][0pt]{%  <=======================================
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}
      %\normalsize
    }
  }
}
% Page Layout for normal pages
\newpairofpagestyles{normalpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{}
  \ofoot{}
}

% Abstaende
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subparagraph}

% 
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\enlargethispage{-1cm}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{normalpage}

\section{First section}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\Blindtext[2]

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\Blindtext[6]

\section{Second section}

\Blindtext[9]

\end{document}
```

you will get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `\raisebox{0.25cm}[0pt][0pt]` as the XYZ is a little too low in my opinion for 0cm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion defining a new layer for the footer on the first page:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch \maketitle (page style and shorten the page)

\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = 2\baselineskip,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\ihead{Inner head}
\ohead{Outer head}

% declare a new layer for the footer on the first page
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\vfill
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\dp\strutbox\relax}{%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
            \textbf{An organization}\\
            With an address\\
            and communication channels
          \end{tabular}%
        }%
        \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
          Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only%
        }%
    }%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}%
    }%
  }
]{firstpage.foot}

% declare a new page style using layer firstpage.foot
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firstpage.foot}
% add the head layers from scrheadings to page style firstpage
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head.}{\AddLayersToPageStyle{firstpage}{#1}}{}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip,
  font=\normalsize
]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\xapptocmd{\maketitle}{\enlargethispage{-5\baselineskip}\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\Blindtext[6]
\section{Second section}
\Blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```

Note that for the "normal" pages the default page style `scrheadings` is used and that I have removed the unrelated stuff.

Result with package `showframe`:

[image]

Result without package `showframe`:

[image]

It is also possible to add a sep line above the footer on the first page using an additional layer:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch \maketitle (page style and shorten the page)

\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = 2\baselineskip,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\ihead{Inner head}
\ohead{Outer head}

% declare a new layer for the footer on the first page
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\vfill
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\dp\strutbox\relax}{%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
            \textbf{An organization}\\
            With an address\\
            and communication channels
          \end{tabular}%
        }%
        \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
          Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only%
        }%
    }%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}%
    }%
  }
]{firstpage.foot}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.foot.above.line,
  textarea,
  addvoffset=\textheight-4\baselineskip
]{firstpage.foot.above.line}

% declare a new page style using layer firstpage.foot
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers[oninit=\KOMAoptions{footsepline}]{firstpage}{firstpage.foot,firstpage.foot.above.line}
% add the head layers from scrheadings to page style firstpage
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head.}{\AddLayersToPageStyle{firstpage}{#1}}{}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip,
  font=\normalsize
]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\xapptocmd{\maketitle}{\enlargethispage{-5\baselineskip}\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\Blindtext[2]
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\Blindtext[6]
\section{Second section}
\Blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```