# scrlayer-scrpage: 1st page header and footer in scrreprt without titlepage

Tags: header-footer, titles, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

This is sort of a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386493/scrlayer-scrpage-footer-only-on-first-page-adjust-geometry?noredirect=1#comment957790_386493). I want to re-create a Word template for use in LaTeX.

Due to requirements on the sectioning levels, I need to switch from `scrartcl` to `scrreprt`. I know I can increase the numbering level with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{VALUE}` and I also know that mimicing the behaviour of `scrartcl` with `scrreprt` is generelly not a good idea. However, I want to try it.

My template has a constant header in the whole document and a footer, but only on the first page. With `scrartcl` this looks like the following:

[image]
[image]

When I make the move to `scrreprt` I suppress the titlepage with `titlepage=false` in the documentclass options. Additionally, thanks to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24067/44634), I suppress the page break before each chapter. However, when I do that, the header and footer on the first page and the header on the second page are missing. On page 3 the header is back where it is supposed to be.

To get my header and footer on the first page back, I guess I have to somehow modify `\titlepagestyle` and for each chapters first page I have to modify `\chapterpagestyle`. Unfortunately, I only found

```
\renewcommand*\titlepagestyle{firstpage}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{normalpage}
```

`firstpage` and `normalpage` are defined in my preamble. This solves the problem for each chapters first page, but unfortunately not for `\titlepagestyle`. The header of the titlepage is there, but the footer is missing. Changing the style for the first page with `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` does not seem to have an effect.

What am I missing?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,parskip=half-,11pt]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ---------------------------
% Packages
% ---------------------------

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = \dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}

% ---------------------------
% Template adjustments
% ---------------------------

% Title
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  % Zweck
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    Test
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  % Authors
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X}%
      \@author
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Title
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    \@title%
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  %\vskip 1.5em%
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Beschreibung des Vorhabens
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    Schalala
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
}
\makeatother

% Font sizes
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% ---------------------------
% Header/Footer commands
% ---------------------------

% Clear old  headers/footers
\clearpairofpagestyles

% Fonts for headers/footers
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

% Trennlinien fuer Kopf und Fuss
\KOMAoptions{
  headsepline = false,
  footsepline = false,
  plainfootsepline = false,
}

% Create new header for title page
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{%
    %\hspace{-1em}
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \textbf{An organization}\\
      With an address\\
      and communication channels
      \end{tabular}
    }
  }
  \cfoot{%
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only
    }
  }
  \ofoot{%
    \raisebox{0.25cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}
      %\normalsize
    }
  }
}
% Page Layout for normal pages
\newpairofpagestyles{normalpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{}
  \ofoot{}
}

\renewcommand*\titlepagestyle{firstpage}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{normalpage}

% Abstaende
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{subparagraph}

% 
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

% No chapter page break: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24067/44634
% for report:
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
%\makeatother
% for scrreprt:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Stuff at begin of document       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\AtBeginDocument{
  \maketitle
  \enlargethispage{-1cm}
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
  \pagestyle{normalpage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section 1}

\Blindtext[2]

\section{Section 2}

\Blindtext[6]

\chapter{Second chapter}

\Blindtext[9]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not patch an internal KOMA-Script command. If your chapters should behave like sections, redeclare the chapter level using

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  indent=0pt
]{chapter}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,parskip=half-,11pt]{scrreprt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ---------------------------
% Packages
% ---------------------------
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrlayer-scrpage}% autooneside is default

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=25mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=12mm,
  includefoot=false,
  headsep = \dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax,
  footskip = \dimexpr1\baselineskip+1.5mm\relax,
}
% ---------------------------
% Template adjustments
% ---------------------------
% Title
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  % Zweck
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    Test
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  % Authors
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize%
    \bfseries%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X}%
      \@author
    \end{tabularx}
    \par
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Title
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    \@title%
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  % Abstand
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  %\vskip 1.5em%
  \vskip 1\baselineskip
  % Beschreibung des Vorhabens
  \begingroup%
    \normalsize
    \bfseries
    Schalala
    \par%
  \endgroup%
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
}
\makeatother
% ---------------------------
% Header/Footer commands
% ---------------------------

% Clear old  headers/footers
\clearpairofpagestyles
% Fonts for headers/footers
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily}% not needed
%\setkomafont{pagination}{}% there is no \pagemark in your pagestyles??

% Trennlinien fuer Kopf und Fuss
%\KOMAoptions{
  %headsepline = false,% false is default
  %footsepline = false,% false is default
  %plainfootsepline = false,% false is default
%}

% Create new header for title page
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
  \ifoot{%
    %\hspace{-1em}
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \textbf{An organization}\\
      With an address\\
      and communication channels
      \end{tabular}
    }
  }
  \cfoot{%
    \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      Footer on 1\textsuperscript{st} page only
    }
  }
  \ofoot{%
    \raisebox{0.25cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      {\fontsize{37}{44}\selectfont XYZ}
      %\normalsize
    }
  }
}
% Page Layout for normal pages
\newpairofpagestyles{normalpage}{%
  \ihead{Inner head}
  \ohead{Outer head}
}

% \chapter should behave like a section
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  indent=0pt
]{chapter}

% Abstaende
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip,
  font=\normalsize
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

%\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}% <- remove this
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% instead option parskip=half- and \setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Stuff at begin of document       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtBeginDocument{
  \maketitle
  \enlargethispage{-1cm}
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
  \pagestyle{normalpage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Section 2}
\Blindtext[6]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\Blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

Additional remarks:

If all section levels should use the same `font`, `beforeskip` and `afterskip` the code can be shortened:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip,
  font=\normalsize
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Options `autooneside`, `headsepline=false`, `footsepline=false`, `plainfootsepline=false` are default.

I do not understand why you firstly set option `parskip=half-` and then `\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}`. Do not change `\parskip` manually! It seems to me that you want neither a parskip nor a parindent. Then you have to set `\parindent` to `0pt`. Note that then the start of new paragraph is not really visible.

Instead of defining the new page style `normalstyle` you could use the default style `scrheadings`.