# No page number after afterpage

Tags: page-numbering, geometry, afterpage

Why is no page number shown on the page after the one generated by afterpage?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{afterpage, geometry, lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum

\afterpage{%
\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
foo
\restoregeometry
\clearpage
}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd think that `\afterpage` is needed in 0.00001% of documents and `\newgeometry` needed in a similar amount, so the number of documents needing `\newgeometry` in `\afterpage` should be ... small....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A page number is not shown because you set `\thispagestyle{empty}`. If you remove that line the page number will be set at the bottom center of the page, but `\newgeometry{margin=1cm}` pushes it off the page.

To restore the original page geometry after the `\afterpage`, use `\aftergroup\restoregeometry` (thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40503/24974)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{afterpage, geometry, lipsum}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{afterpage, geometry, lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\lipsum
\afterpage{%
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{margin=4cm}
foo
\clearpage
\aftergroup\restoregeometry %
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having no page number on the "foo" page is intended. However, if I use margin=4cm the page number indeed shows up on the last page. Why is that? Shouldn't \restoregeometry followed by \clearpage set the geometry of the last page to the same than the first?
margin=1cm should only be set for the "foo" page.

Comment: Replace `\restoregeometry` with `\aftergroup\restoregeometry` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40503/24974)

Comment: You're welcome. I had misunderstood your initial question, so I've edited my answer.